# How find and change the name of a website (not url & domain name)

Tags: web, seo, meta-tags, google-search, meta

I woud like to know which information refers to the name of a website on Google Searchs (or any other Search's motors)
In exemple an url could be :
         my-creations.com
and the google name (clic link):
        "My Super Creations"

Is this name (My super creation) whritten in html -> meta ? how can i change it ? If i change it, my SEO result will be lower ?

Thanks for your responses and help :)
And excuse my english

```
<div id="thanks"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Search engines usually use the value of the `title` element:

```html
<head>
  <title>Page and site name</title>
</head>
```

Some search engines, [for example Google](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21493507/1591669), might display something else when they think it’s more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The site web i'm working for use Adobe Muse (yep i know...). So the html is generated and here is the title :

```
<title>home</title>
```

And as you can imagine "home" is not the name of the website as result on google.
So.... anyone knows if Adobe Muse put another information anywhere ?