# google search doesn't show correct title and description

Tags: web, seo, search-engine, google-search-console

Please search google for `amirkabir data miners`
Check Title and Description for https://adm-co.net
As you can see in page source, google show `Amirkabir Data Miners: داده کاوان امیرکبیر` instead of `داده کاوان امیرکبیر | Amirkabir Data Miners` and completely **wrong** description.
I registered site in Google Webmaster Tools, and Google Analytics and tried anything.
What do i have to do!?

```
    <title>داده کاوان امیرکبیر | Amirkabir Data Miners</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/Content/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/Content/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/Content/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/Content/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/Content/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/Content/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/Content/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/Content/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/Content/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/Content/images/favicons/favicon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/Content/images/favicons/favicon-160x160.png" sizes="160x160">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/Content/images/favicons/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/Content/images/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/Content/images/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#e3e3e3">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-144x144.png">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    <meta name="description" content="شرکت داده کاوان امیرکبیر | تولید کننده نرم افزارهای تحت وب، از قبیل حسابداری آنلاین 'کاج سیستم' ، سیستم مدیریت پروژه 'تسک من' و ...">
    <meta name="keywords" content="شرکت داده کاوان امیرکبیر,شرکت,داده,کاوان,امیرکبیر,حسابداری, سیستم های تحت وب, برنامه نویسی,حسابداری آنلاین,سیستم های تحت وب, طراحی نرم افزار, adm, amikabir, data, miners, amirkabir data miners, adm (amirkabir data miners), programming, financial, taskman, taskmanager, web application, web, application">
    <meta name="language" content="fa">
    <meta name="robots" content="all" />
    <meta name="rights" content="Copyright © 2015 ADM-CO - All rights reserved">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google displaying website title differently in search results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387047/google-displaying-website-title-differently-in-search-results)

Answer (score 1):

Many are getting similar kind of issues, Before Google has automatically set the Meta description when it is not presented in the site. It sets the description as per the search query and based on the content in the website.

Now the Google does the same for the Meta Title and Meta Description even though it is presented in the website.

Comment: Yes, it is at Google's discretion. Seems for some reason Google thinks your title and snippet (description) should be other.