# Why site name is first show for title in Google Search Results

Tags: wordpress, seo, google-search

I have create my website built with **wordpress**. http://www.harnishdesign.net/

and, I have put following Title for HomePage. (Site Title | Site Name)

```
OpenCart Themes | eCommerce HTML Templates | HarnishDesign
```

but, **In Google Search Results.** My site name does first show in title. please see following image.
[image]

I have define site name in last position for title. It is working fine in inner pages & also, post.

Why site name does first show in HomePage?

Comment: Maybe it's your previous title and google haven't updated it yet?

Comment: @Picard No, this is not previous title. I was change title many time. and, google have updated. but, every time Site name does first show. I can't not understand. why this happen.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score -1):

Homepage meta data looks ok, so most probably it is just a matter of time.

[image]

You can try to speed up things submitting homepage link via Google Search Console: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en

Cheers

Comment: I think, I have trying. but, though, i will try again. & then will see, what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Now looks like site title is properly displayed in Google results

Comment: ya, it has been working fine 1 days ago. Thanks.

Comment: You are not wrong. but I was used site name as name(Mr. Harnish) in content. I have removed it. I think, it will cause. This answer helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387047/google-displaying-website-title-differently-in-search-results