# Website title on Google is wrong

Tags: angular, google-search, html-title

I have this element within `<head></head>`:

```html
<title>Bau- und Möbelschreiner Mustermann</title>
```

but on Google it's displayed as

```
und Möbelschreiner Mustermann: Bau
```

Additionally I added a `description` meta tag which is displayed correctly:

```html
<meta name="description" content="Bau- und Möbelschreiner Mustermann | Bla Bla Bla" />
```

Am I doing something wrong here? The website is made with Angular 4 (and NOT rendered on server side).

Comment: [Google displaying website title differently in search results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21387047/1591669)

Comment: I also think that it does not have anything to do with angular. I've got a classic website (PHP) and the title is not exactly the one indicated. Also, the title for the landing page itsel changes depending on the search query on google...

Comment: DId you already have a website at this domain before? With correct title?

Comment: Yes, before I used angular the title was correct

Answer (score 6):

Check the encoding of your html file should be

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

and maybe set the language

At least here it works for a Bau- und Möbelschreiner

https://www.google.de/search?q=Bau-+und+M%C3%B6belschreiner&rlz=1C1GCEA_enDE767DE767&oq=Bau-+und+M%C3%B6belschreiner&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.719j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

**Edit**

If you are not sure how google sees your site then you might try their debugging tools on https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/debug

Comment: I had this meta already, but I had language "en", changed it to "de". I will see if google accepts it... Thanks

Comment: hey, changing the lang did not help... UTF8 is already set correctly, too

Comment: do you have a url for the site?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add an `<html lang="de">` on top of the index.html (after the !doctype, but before the head) and please enter an `<meta charset="utf-8">` as first tag in the `<head>` tag.

That is the only thing I can imagine, what could scramble up this stuff. I never experienced this kind of problem before

Comment: *"and please enter an `<meta charset="utf-8">` as first tag in the `<head>` tag."* Assuming, of course, the resource is delivered in UTF-8, and not some other encoding. Just blindly adding an encoding tag without ensuring it actually matches the encoding being used would be bad.

Comment: I had this meta already, but I had language "en", changed it to "de". I will see if google accepts it... Thanks

Comment: hey, changing the lang did not help... UTF8 is already set correctly

Comment: sorry, was worth the shot